# In Rackspace cloud, it is true that a 2GB server is faster than the default 256MB server?

Tags: linux, unix, cloud, rackspace

For example...when I do string.find("..."), will it be faster because the CPU is allocated more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very likely. And no - you should not see a difference in ONE string.find method call.

The limiting factor on most virutalization platforms is CPU and memory - you only can have that much memory and that much CPU power in one box. So, you have to keep them "aligned" by basically assuming every slice of memory comes with a slice of CPU. As such, a 2gb server will get a larger slice than a 256mb server. Totally natural.

This is normally / should be done by reservations of some part (distributing like x% of the CPU as reservations) and then giving higher allocation priorities to larger machines.

That said, unless everyone uses up his slice, the excess CPU should be available for all.

Comment: What if I have a list of 500 strings, and I am doing .find on all of them. Will I see noticible difference?

Comment: That totally depends. 500 strings - not likely in a visible area. I personally dont use them - I have my own server cluster for hosting - but I use virtualization heavily. It really depends how loaded their CPU's are. And how much CPU you use on a continuous level. Small spikes may not even be noticable. Running a raytrace is.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Rackspace site:

> All Cloud Servers come with a certain amount of guaranteed CPU power based on the size of 
>   the servers you create. However, at times when there's extra CPU power available from the
>   host hardware, we take advantage of it, providing your workloads extra processing power
>   without any additional cost to you.